# laravel 5 сделать 404 страницу

Tags: php, laravel

Как сделать *404* страницу?

Пытался задать в `App\Exceptions\Handler` в методе

```
render - return view("");
```

В итоге не отображается и выдает ошибку.

В общем, мне нужно конкретно определенный шаблон указать, когда не найден роут.
Стартовый от laravel "not found" не устраивает.

Ну или скажите, где можно стартовый отредактировать.

Answer (score 6):

O_o а не проще просто создать вьюху `404.blade.php` в `resources/views/errors` и вуаля... работает автоматом... аналогично 403, 401 и т.д

Answer (score 0):

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
        return view('404', [], 404);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Где исключение вида:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
```

А так как без этого класса вывод ошибок сломается, нужно позаботиться о стандартном выводе ошибок PHP для отладки, а проще `php -l` для файла запустить для проверки

Comment: По правде говоря, вообще ничего не понял.
В if указал свой view
  if ($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
        return view('404.blade.php', [], 404);
    }
В итоге это условие не срабатывает, срабатывает все тот же вывод ошибок parent::render().
При этом вывод ошибок отключил

Comment: @Andrey А до этого как узнавал, что 404?

Comment: [статья целая](https://github.com/laravel/blog-contest-may-mayhem/issues/17) ток может не открыться благодаря РГКН )